# Need To Open An MDI Child Form From A Non MDI Child Form

Tags: vb.net, mdi, mdichild

I have the scenario where I am opening a form outside of an MDI parent using the following code:

```
Dim frm As New frmSpeedSearch
frm.Show(Me)
```

I then want the ability to open an MDI child from this frmSpeedSearch.
FrmMain is the MDI Parent of all child forms.
From the frmSpeedSearch, I make the following call:

```
Dim frm As New frmStorePage(_store)
frm.Owner = frmMain
frm.Show()
```

But this just opens the form normally.  How can I push this back into the MDI Parent container?
Within frmStorePage I make a call to the MdiParent which is failing because the form doesn't have an MDI Parent when I open it this way

```
Dim frm As frmDashBoard
frm = DirectCast(Me.MdiParent, frmMain)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed the MdiParent to frmSpeedSearch when you called Show().

As such, you can do:

```
Dim frm As New frmStorePage(_store)
frm.MdiParent = Me.Owner
frm.Show()
```

Comment: Wow...as simple as that!  Thankyou for the speedy response - exactly what I needed!